# How to compare standard deviations of different sample sizes

Tags: statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

- I am interested in estimating the value of an unknown, random variable, X.
- X changes over time. So, X = X(t) = X<sub>t</sub>
- At specific time intervals, I estimate the value of X<sub>t</sub> using 7 different methods.
- Some methods randomly fail in their estimation of X. i.e., they return a null value.
- Therefore, each estimate of X<sub>t</sub>, returns a set of estimates (sample pool size = N<sub>t</sub>) where N<sub>t</sub> <= 7.
- I estimate X as the median of my sample of N data points.
- **I want to compare the "spread" between the data points in each pool, across different pools.** (In other words, how "close together" or "far apart" are the points in my sample pool of estimates at time t1, t2, ..., tn.)
- Let's call the sample standard deviation of the N points at time t, S(t) = S<sub>t</sub> = stdDev(N<sub>t</sub>)

## Question

> **Would it be correct to compute a variable Y<sub>t</sub> = S<sub>t</sub>/N<sub>t</sub> and compare Y<sub>t</sub> across all estimates at times t1, t2, ... tn?**
>
> Or, alternatively, maybe the formula should be:
>
> Y<sub>t</sub> = S<sub>t</sub>/(N<sub>t</sub>-1)

In other words, conclude that higher values of Y<sub>t</sub> represent a higher "spread" situation? And, therefore, less confidence in my estimate of X<sub>t</sub>?